# .NET ODAC query returning no results, but SQL DEVELOPER returns results

Tags: c#, oracle

When I execute a simple select query in SQL Developer against a newly added table or an older table with newly added data, I receive results.  But if I run the exact same query in .NET/C# using the most recent Oracle Data Access Client under .NET 4.0, I receive zero results.

I have verified the connection string is correct, and that I am connecting to the same DB, and I have tested using simple "select * from table" queries. Using the same exact .NET code querying against older data...it works just fine.  I can only conclude that this is a bug of some sort, or maybe someone who is an Oracle expert knows how this can occur. I know DBs are complex machines and therefore I am hoping there is some logical explanation as to how this can occur...and how I can fix it.

I am an Oracle newbie, but I am a veteran programmer and problem solver. This one really has me stumped.

This is my first SO question, so please be gentle...thanks!

Here is my sample code that returns error saying "...table does not exist...".  But table DOES exist and the query works fine in SQL DEV.

```
        String prod_connstr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = 10.0.0.17) (PORT = 2621)) " +
        "(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XXXXX)));User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX";

        String sqlStr = "select * from z_test";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(prod_connstr);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlStr, conn);
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show(dr.HasRows.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
        finally
        {

            conn.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time I have seen "...table does not exist..." where you know it does, it means the user you are connecting as (in the connection string) does not have select granted to it.  Now if you are connecting with SQL developer and you connection string with the same schema, you have me stumped.

edit: as Oğuz Sezer pointed out if your db doesn't have public synonyms for the tables you will need to use Schema.table (forgot about that)

Comment: You nailed it. I was sure I had the right userID because it had been working for all other queries.  But on closer examination it turned out I had the wrong userID.  Changed it...and voila!  It works!  Hey, I like this SO thingy.

Comment: Ran into same issue....stumped all day.  Connection credentials were EXACTLY the same....but this post triggered me to add grant access to user ANONYMOUS.  That did it.  I'm not sure why....but it worked.  PS. My tables were generated from Oracle Data Modeler, so maybe the import goofed up the "owner" deep inside the bowels of the beast....